# redhat-idm-console removing or adding accounts takes a longtime to take effect

Tags: redhat, directory-services

Using the redhat-idm-console tool often takes a long time to allow the changes to be reflected in directory services. Closing Firefox and clearing the cache does not seem to have any noticeable effect. Eventually after an unknown period of time, the account no longer works. The same happens for adding an account. Eventually the account is recognized in directory services. Any idea on why this is the case and how to fix it? Is there another command to do immediate update instead of having to wait?

Comment: How are you checking for the updates you've made after making them?

Comment: @John: By attempting to login to the webpage.

Comment: And how does the web page authenticate? Through PAM services? Or directly to LDAP?

Comment: @John: LDAP, we use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there's some sort of server-side caching going on in the web application itself. On a system level, this behavior can occur when using LDAP authentication cached by NSCD. If this is the case, then closing the client-side browser would have no effect as the caching is happening server-side. What is doing the caching is what you'll have to trace down inside the web application, but in general, updates made to LDAP are effective immediately when checking directly against the source (versus going through a caching mechanism).